# VBA XML - Reading & looping through 2 different branches of an XML file

Tags: xml, vba

I searched, tested and read a lot, but couldn't get it. Please consider the following XML file:

For each "Element" I try to extract the "date* from the branch  AND the texts "some text" from the branch . The result should give in Excel (cell after cell): date1, some_text1, some_text2, some_text3, some_text4, some_text5, some_text6. And then, next line: date2, some_text7, some_text8, some_text9, some_text10, some_text11, some_text12 (etc.)

```
<Tree>

  <Element ID="1">
    <Head>
      <Created>date1</Created>
    </Head>
    <Body>
      <Version Nr="1">
        <Signal ID="878465">
          <Text1>some_text1</Text1>
          <Text2>some_text2</Text2>
          <Text3>some_text3</Text3>
        </Signal>
        <Signal ID="2654647">
          <Text1>some_text4</Text1>
          <Text2>some_text5</Text2>
          <Text3>some_text6</Text3>
        </Signal>
      </Version>
    </Body>
  </Element>

  <Element ID="2">
    <Head>
      <Created>date2</Created>
    </Head>
    <Body>
      <Version Nr="2">
        <Signal ID="48554568">
          <Text1>some_text7</Text1>
          <Text2>some_text8</Text2>
          <Text3>some_text9</Text3>
        </Signal>
        <Signal ID="89243565">
          <Text1>some_text10</Text1>
          <Text2>some_text11</Text2>
          <Text3>some_text12</Text3>
        </Signal>
      </Version>
    </Body>
  </Element>

  <Element ID="3">
    <Head>
      <Created>date3</Created>
    </Head>
    <Body>
      <Version Nr="3">
        <Signal ID="34547856">
          <Text1>some_text13</Text1>
          <Text2>some_text14</Text2>
          <Text3>some_text15</Text3>
        </Signal>
        <Signal ID="34634567">
          <Text1>some_text16</Text1>
          <Text2>some_text17</Text2>
          <Text3>some_text18</Text3>
        </Signal>
      </Version>
    </Body>
  </Element>

</Tree>
```

Either it does not loop properly or it shows always only the value of the first node.

My code looks like this (albeit I have tried several variants):

```
Sub test1

Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim Entry, Thing As Object
Dim Created, Version_Nr, Text1, Text2, Text3 As String

Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = True
XDoc.Load("C:\MyXML.xml")

Set Entry = XDoc.SelectNodes("//Tree/Element")
    For Each Thing In Entry
        Created = Thing.SelectSingleNode(".//Created").Text
        'write Created in a cell

         Version_Nr = Thing.SelectSingleNode(".//Body/Version").Attributes.getNamedItem("Nr").Text
         'write Version_Nr in a cell 

         Text1 = Thing.SelectSingleNode(".//Text1").Text
         Text2 = Thing.SelectSingleNode(".//Text2").Text
         Text3 = Thing.SelectSingleNode(".//Text3").Text
         'write the Text1, Text2, Text3 (which shall contain some_text1, some_text2, some_text3) in cells
    Next Thing

    Set XDoc = Nothing   

End sub
```

I was actually also thinking to something like this (one loop i for "Element" and one loop j for the "Text1", "Text2", etc) and use the version_nr as variable in a loop - but this code is completely buggy:

```
Sub test2

Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim Entry As Object
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim Created, Version_Nr, Text1, Text2, Text3 As String

Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = True
XDoc.Load("C:\MyXML.xml")

Set Entry = XDoc.SelectNodes("//Tree/Element")
    For i = 1 To Entry.Length
        Created = XDoc.SelectSingleNode(".//Created").Text
        For j = 1 To Entry(i).ChildNodes.Length
           Version_Nr = Entry.SelectSingleNode(".//Body/Version").Attributes.getNamedItem("Nr").Text
           Text1 = Entry.SelectSingleNode(".//Text1").Text
           Text2 = Entry.SelectSingleNode(".//Text2").Text
           Text3 = Entry.SelectSingleNode(".//Text3").Text
        Next j
    Next i

    Set XDoc = Nothing   

End sub
```

Does anybody have an elegant idea to access simultaneously "date" and the "some_text" values "Element" after "Element" ?

Thanks!

---

Edit 1
Correction of several typos, wrong XML (sorry...) and added full VBA code

Edit 2
Thanks a lot to all - you are so fast to answer. Amazing !

Comment: Are you sure that you have *valid* XML? This thing - `ID=1` - tells me that not.

Comment: Please include all `Dim` and assignment lines for **runnable** [MCVE].

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` specified somewhere? Remove it.

Comment: Yes, it is ID="1", I fix/edit it in the code and add the Dim. There is no On Error Resume Next in the code.

Comment: Any help anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

```
Sub ProcessXML()

    '// Tools -> References -> Microsoft XML, v6.0
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim element_nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim element_node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim signal_node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim text_node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    doc.Load "PATH_TO_FILE"

    With doc.parseError
        If .ErrorCode <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "XML parsing error: " & .reason & Chr(10) & "at: " & .srcText
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Set element_nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Tree/Element")
    For Each element_node In element_nodes
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        Cells(r, "A") = element_node.SelectSingleNode("Head/Created").Text
        For Each signal_node In element_node.SelectNodes("Body/Version/Signal")
            For Each text_node In signal_node.ChildNodes
                c = c + 1: Cells(r, c) = text_node.Text
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I study your solution and come back to reply.

Comment: When you write ```Cells(r, c) = text_node.Text```, it writes  "some_text1 some_text2 some_text3" together. Any way to split the whole and have it separated ?

Comment: Also: the XML Structure was wrong and was updated (added several "Signal" nodes in each "Version" node). Can you fetch also the 2nd signal entries in each version node ?

Comment: @Sam77 The text can't be concatenated 'cause the column where it's written to is always incremented in a loop: `c = c + 1`. As for updated structure, I'll take a look.

Comment: The result should be 1 node value = 1 cell in Excel. Is it not possible with something like ```Cells(r,c)=text_node.SelectSingleNodes("version").Text``` ? (I tried this but got an error)

Comment: Many thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. To summarize the solution, it consists in a new For loop for each branch of the tree.

Comment: @Sam77 Yes, it iterates over each `Element` node and then dive into `Signal` nodes. Take a note that code uses `ChildNodes` (i.e. without searching for `Text*` node) since these are the only elements beneath `Signal`.